# Make Div buttons using jQuery - .show/.toggle/.hide?

Tags: jquery

I have 4 buttons which are Divs styled with CSS. What I want is to show/hide data which is contained in another Div upon each button click.

I'm using jQuery to do this, at the moment I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#aboutbody").hide();
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $aboutbody = $('#aboutbody');
        $('#about').on('click', function () {
            $aboutbody.show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

`#about` is my button and `#aboutbody` is the content i'd like to display. I've tried copying the above code for all of my buttons which sort of works however they only display when clicked in corresponding order??

Comment: what do you mean by "when clicked in corresponding order"? can you make a fiddle??

Comment: And you should realise that there can only be one unique id ("#about" and "#aboutbody") in an HTML page

Comment: I mean that you have to click on button 1 first before you can click on button 2. Then click on button 2 before you can click on button 3.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle (jsfiddle) as asked by Hannan Hossain? That would be helfull.

Comment: I'm changing the Div button ID and the Div content ID everytime of course.

Comment: If you keep ignoring our messages about jsfiddle, I don't know how we're gonna help you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gyLz4/ - its showing the content however which i dont want it to do unless each button is clicked on (first, second, third)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

should be used just one time. What you put in is the code which will be executed when the document is "ready" (loaded).

Your #secondbody div is in the firstbody div, so yes, it needs firstbody to be shown.

```
<div id="firstbody">
    <div class=".main">
        Information to be displayed when First is clicked ont
    </div>
</div><br><br>

<div id="secondbody">
    <div class=".main">
        <span>Information to be displayed when second is clicked</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="thirdbody">
    <div class=".main">
        <span>Information to be displayed when Third is clicked</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gyLz4/1/

Comment: Oh by the way, don't forget to always close a HTML tag (thinking about your span and div elements)!